# After changing the default port number, how should I start Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

To change the default port number of Apache IoTDB, do I need to delete the original data directory before restarting IoTDB? Or can I directly restart Apache IoTDB after I changed the default port number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify `dn_rpc_port` setting, then Apache IoTDB can be started directly, without the need to modify the original data directory.